# New conda environment without internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda3

I am trying to create a new conda environment using pycharm on a computer without access to the internet.

When I try to create it it throws an error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
```

I assume that the pycharm is trying to access the internet but it can't.
Is there a way to make it work locally?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
conda create -n envname --clone root --offline
```

You could try cloning a pre-existing conda environment or use the `root` base env.